# Joomla 2.5 authentication Plugin Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I wrote a simple authentication plugin that uses a SOAP webservice to check the username and the password. That works fine.

I wanted to have some parameter like the SOAP password in the admin of joomla. So I have added the params in the xml, it shows fine in the admin. When I try to get the value of it the php, I get:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

So I compared with other authentication and I do it exactly the same way.... I do not understand why it is so.

Here is the code of the Plugin:

```
public function __construct() {
    $nusoap = JPATH_SITE . '/plugins/authentication/ers/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
    if (! file_exists ( $nusoap )){
                $response->error_message = "No such file";
        return;
            }
    require_once ($nusoap);

}



function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response)
{



        //Without defaults (the plugin crashes on the first get() bellow)
        $webservice = $this->params->get('webservice', '');
        $group      = $this->params->get('group', '');
        $whitepaw   = $this->params->get('whitepaw', '');



        JRequest::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
        // For JLog
        $response->type = 'ERS SOAP Webservice';

            // MyCompany does not like blank passwords (So does Joomla ;))
    if (empty($credentials['password'])) {
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_EMPTY_PASS_NOT_ALLOWED');
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($credentials['username'])) {
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = JText::_('Please enter a username');
        return false;
    }

           // Add a user to joomla
                function addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email, $group) {

                            $data = array(
                                "name"=>$name,
                                "username"=>$username,
                                "password"=>$password,
                                "password2"=>$password,
                                "email"=>$email,
                                "block"=>0,
                                "groups"=>array("1","2", $group) // the uer is added into the group "public" and "registered" as well as a group of the user's choice.

                            );

                            $user = clone(JFactory::getUser());
                            //Write to database
                            if(!$user->bind($data)) {
                                throw new Exception("Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError());
                            }
                            if (!$user->save()) {
                                throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
                            }

                        return $user->id;
                }


            // Pour supprimer le cache du web-service
            ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

            // Nouveau Client SOAP
            try {

                // Nouvelle instance de la classe soapClient
                $client = new SoapClient($webservice, array('trace' => true));


                $username = $credentials['username'];
                $password = $credentials['password'];



                $result = $client->CheckLogin(array('whitepaw'=>$whitepaw, 'username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));

                if($result->isInDB){


                        $name = $result->fname.' '.$result->lname;
                        $email = $result->email;

                        $response->error_message = $username.'<br>'.$password.'<br>'.$name.'<br>'.$email."<br><br>".
                                "<b>Request :</b><br>".htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest())."<br><br>".
                                "<b>RESPONSE :</b><br>".htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse())."<br><br>";

                        if(!$result->email == '' || empty ($result)) {
                            //Todo: check if the user is already in joomla db
                            $user_id = addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email,$group);
                            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
                            //for testing purposes
                            $response->error_message = $user_id;
                      } else {
                           $response->error_message = "The webservice did not return data".$email.'did you see it?';

                       }

                } else {
                    $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
                    $response->error_message = 'You do not have yet an account in <a href="http://my.ersnet.org">myers</a>. Please register.<br>';
                    $response->error_message .= $result->isInDB;

                }
                } catch (Exception $fault) {
                    $response->error_message = $fault->getMessage();
                }




}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your own constructor, you need to call the parent constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(& $subject, $params = array()) {
    $nusoap = JPATH_SITE . '/plugins/authentication/ers/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
    if (! file_exists ( $nusoap )){
                $response->error_message = "No such file";
        return;
            }
    require_once ($nusoap);
    // call the parent constructor
    parent::__construct($subject, $params);
}
```

The parent constructor is where the `$this->params` object gets set, so if you don't call it then `$this->params` is never set. That's why you get the error saying `params` is not an object.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the logic of your answer. I have tried but now it asks me for missing arguments... why so? in my constructor, I have none.

Comment: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for JPlugin::__construct(), called in /home/forum/public_html/plugins/authentication/ers/ers.php on line 30 and defined in /home/forum/public_html/libraries/joomla/plugin/plugin.php on line 55 Fatal error: Call to a member function attach() on a non-object in /home/forum/public_html/libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 39` but if I remove the constructor and call the lib nusoap in the plugin method every thing is fine... @MrCode

Comment: @Wiglaf Edited my answer, there is a `$subject` argument that it needs.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function attach() on a non-object in /home/forum/public_html/libraries/joomla/event/event.php on line 39` There is maybe another one ?